# Water Volume Fill and Drain Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, newtonian-gravity, flow, volume

I have a pump that will (according to the instructions) pump 450 litres of water per minute.

Water is pumped into a box that can hold 85 litres. This box has 3×1.5 inch holes in a row on one side, near the bottom of the box. One on the left. One in the center, and one on the right. :)

I'm trying to solve a problem of the box overflowing after so many minutes/seconds of the pump being switched on. Due to this, the pump then needs to be switched off again for a few minutes to allow the box to drain slightly, before resuming.

> **Question:** What size box do I need, in order to handle this amount of water? Preventing the need of switching the pump off after so long?

Comment: Why not let the box overflow? Or direct the pump to where the holes lead?

Comment: Are the holes open to the atmosphere, or do they feed into tubes? If tubes, please provide more information. This will affect how fast water drains through the holes, which is key to the calculation. Better still, can you measure how long it takes for the tank to drain when 1 or all 3 holes (valves?) are opened? Ideal would be a table of height of water level v time.

Answer (score 1):

What matters is the height of the box, i.e. the depth of water inside it, not the volume.

Suppose the water flowing out through the holes is flowing with velocity $v$ and the total area of the holes is $A$, then the volume per second, $V$, flowing through the holes is:

$$ V = vA $$

You need this to be equal to or greater than the $7.5$ litres per second flowing in for the box to not overflow. The velocity is given by [Torricelli's law](http://Torricelli's%20law):

$$ v = \sqrt{2gh} $$

Where $h$ is the head of the water. Combine these two equations and you get:

$$ V = \sqrt{2gh}A $$

and this rearranges to give the depth of the box you need:

$$ h = \frac{V^2}{2gA^2} $$

If we take the flow rate $V$ as $450$ litres per minute this is $0.0075$ m$^3$/s. The area of the three holes is $3\pi r^2$, where $r$ is the radius in metres ($r=0.0191$ m) and putting this in the equation I get a depth of $h = 0.245$ m. Torricelli's law is an approximation that ignores viscosity, so add a bit onto this depth to give a margin for error.

Comment: Thanks! :) - So it doesn't matter how wide the container is, as long as there is approx a height of 0.245 metres of water?

Comment: @Richy: Yes, within reason. If you make the tank really narrow that will impede the water flow.